# Why do we remove the foam from soymilk while it boils while preparing it?

Tags: drinks, soymilk, soybeans

Why is the foam removed? Here is the recipe I am following, from Chinese Cooking Demystified.

[How to Make Soy Milk, from Scratch (豆浆)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9nxEsNe84U)

Ingredients:

- Soybeans, 200g
- Water, 2.4L
- Sugar, to taste (we used 3 tbsp)

Process:

1. Pick out any bad soybeans, rinse.
2. Put your water ~2 inches above your soybeans, soak overnight.
3. Blend on high for ~4 minutes. We used the smoothie setting on our blender.
4. Transfer to a wok or stockpot. Medium high flame.
5. Stir and get the soymilk up to 100C.
6. Boil at 100C for 15 minutes, removing the foam.
7. Taste, make sure it's not bitter.
8. Strain through a tofu or cheesecloth. Twist and squeeze out what's left, ~3-5 minutes. Get as much as you can!
9. Season with sugar, to taste. We used ~3 tbsp.

Comment: could it be some excess starch?

Comment: It's common to skim froth with a lot of pulses/legumes, but [advice I see says froth is harmless](https://www.theguardian.com/food/2019/apr/05/do-you-really-need-to-skim-the-surface-when-cooking-pulses) and the main reason for skimming is that it doesn't look nice - and possibly because it makes it harder to see how they're cooking. Not sure if this exactly applies to soy, hence not making it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is to prevent the milk from boiling over. Other recipes like this [one](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/scratch-soy-milk-with-andrea-nguyen) explicitly call out skimming the foam while watching out for it boiling over. Another guess is taste. The foam could effect the taste of the soy milk. From personal experience, the foam doesn't taste as sweet as the rest of the milk so, it could be a mechanism to preserve the natural sweetness.